# Dar acceso a una clase a un miembro privado de otra clase

Tags: c++, clase

Tengo una clase a llamada clase `A` que contiene un objeto de la clase `B`.

```
class A{
  B objeto_b;
};
```

Necesito que `A` pueda acceder a un método privado de la clase `B`. ¿Por qué quiero que sea privado entonces? Porque ese método solo quiero que sea invocado desde un método de la clase `A`, y no que sea público y que pueda ser invocado por cualquier otra parte de mi programa.

¿Por qué no hago que la clase sea amiga? Porque solo necesito garantizar acceso a ese método, no al resto de campos privados.

¿Qué solución proponéis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución pasaría por usar `friend`, pero hay que tener cuidado, ya que al usar `friend` creamos un acoplamiento entre clases que es brutal (más acoplamiento incluso que con herencia)... y además facilita que alguien acceda directamente a las variables miembro de una clase saltándose todas las protecciones habidas y por haber.

Para casos así suelo recurrir a una clase intermedia que me da acceso a lo que yo quiero y nada más:

```
template<class T>
class PassKey
{
  friend T;

  PassKey() = default;
  PassKey(PassKey const&) = default;

  PassKey & operator=(PassKey const&) = delete;
};
```

Clase sencilla a más no poder... no tiene estado ni funciones... solo tiene el constructor base y el constructor copia habilitados y encima son privados... ¿Cómo se usa?

La clave está en el `friend` que tiene dentro. Esta clase solo puede ser creada por el tipo `T`, que será el tipo al que queremos darle acceso a una función de otra clase:

```
class B
{
public:
    void funcionProtegida(PassKey<A>)
    { }
};

class A
{
public:

  void Func()
  { objeto_b.funcionProtegida(PassKey<A>{}); }

private:
  B objeto_b;
};
```

Este código compila, mientras que si otra clase intenta llamar a `funcionProtegida` el compilador no la va a dejar:

```
class C
{
public:

  void Func()
  {
    objeto_b.funcionProtegida(PassKey<A>{}); // Error: PassKey<A>() es un constructor privado
    objeto_b.funcionProtegida(PassKey<C>{}); // Error: No se puede convertir de PassKey<C> a PassKey<A>

  }

private:
  B objeto_b;
};
```

Las principales ventajas de este sistema son:

- consigues un código muy expresivo... en la propia función se ve que tiene un requisito de acceso, así como quien puede acceder.
- El uso de `friend` queda restringido a una clase vacía, lo que genera muy poco acoplamiento
- Sistema fácilmente reutilizable

Contras:

- Entender el funcionamiento de la plantilla puede llevarte unos minutos

Comment: eferion no consigo que compile dice : error: 'PassKey' is not a class template, ¿Es posible que sea así template<class T>
class PassKey{...}; sin el <T> en el nombre de la clase o es cosa de que estoy en C++11?

Comment: Si ese es el estándar que utilizo, pero solo compila si el nombre de la clase es PassKey en lugar de PassKey<T>. En cualquier caso, esta clase es una maravilla.

Comment: @candidatopardo tenias razon.... sobraba el `<T>`... lo copié de una implementación que tengo algo mas compleja... lo siento

Answer (score 3):

Puedes ejecutar una función privada de `B` mediante un puntero a dicha función; la complicación consiste en obtener el puntero en si ya que al apuntar a un dato privado tampoco puedes acceder. Para eso puedes hacer una única función amiga cuya definición no sea accesible más que desde `A`:

`A.hpp`

```
#include "B.hpp"

struct A {
    void f(); // Función que accede a una función privada de B
private:
    B objeto_b;
};
```

`B.hpp`

```
struct B {
    using Bfp = void (B::*)(); // Atajo al tipo de función void() de B
private:
    friend Bfp dame_acceso(); // Función amiga
    void f(); // Función privada de B
};
```

El objeto `B` tiene como amiga una única función, de esta manera no se otorga a `A` ningún tipo de acceso; la función `dame_acceso` devuelve un puntero a función `void B::()` pero no tiene definición. Ocultaremos la definición de `dame_acceso`  en el archivo de código de `A`:

`A.cpp`

```
#include "A.hpp"

// Esta definición sólo es visible aquí
B::Bfp dame_acceso() {
    return &B::f;
}

void A::f() {
    // Llamamos la función privada de B a través del puntero a función
    (objeto_b.*dame_acceso())();
}
```

Al estar la definición de `dame_acceso` en el archivo de código de `A`, la definición no será visible a otras clases y otras clases no podrán obtener el puntero a función privada de `B`. Si se intentase definir otra `dame_acceso` en otra unidad de traducción el programa fallaría al enlazar.

Puedes ver este ejemplo funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U40iM8TSW3Kqt6qq)</kbd>.

---

#### Otra idea.

El puntero a función miembro es extremadamente complicado, puedes conseguir lo mismo con menos código pasando una referencia a `B` a `dame_acceso`:

`A.hpp`

```
#include "B.hpp"

struct A {
    void f(); // Función que acceder a una función privada de B
private:
    B objeto_b;
};
```

`B.hpp`

```
struct B {
private:
    friend void dame_acceso(B &); // Función amiga
    void f(); // Función privada de B
};
```

`A.cpp`

```
#include "A.hpp"

// Esta definición sólo es visible aquí
void dame_acceso(B &b) {
    b.f();
}

void A::f() {
    // Llamamos la función privada de B a través del puntero a función
    dame_acceso(objeto_b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución utilizando los modificadores de acceso pasa por utilizar el modificador **`friendly`**, pero no entre las clases A y B sino **entre un método de la clase A con la clase B**. De este modo, **solo el método será amigo de la clase B** teniendo acceso a sus atributos y demás métodos, pero el resto de la clase A no tendrá acceso a B, así como tampoco otras clases externas.

Por ejemplo (utilizando Visual Studio C++, que es lo que tengo a mano):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

class B;

class A
{
public:
    A();
    int RestaA(B);//Este es el método que utilizaremos para acceder al método de B
};


class B
{
public:
    B(int parametroNumero1 = 0, int parametroNumero2 = 0) : numero1(parametroNumero1), numero2(parametroNumero2) {}
private:        
    int numero1;
    int numero2;
    int RestaB()//Este es el método B, es privado por lo que no es accesible por ninguna clase      
    {
            return numero1 - numero2;
    };
    friend int A::RestaA(B b);//Declaramos como amigo el método RestaA, por lo que ahora solo este método puede acceder a los atributos y métodos de B
};


int A::RestaA(B b)
{
    return b.RestaB();//Podemos ejecutar sin problema el método RestaB de B
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    A a;
    B b(25, 10);
    cout << a.RestaA(b) << endl; //Ejecutamos el método RestaA de la clase A el cual internamente ejecuta el método RestaB de la clase B.

    return 0;
}
```

De esta forma, mantenemos la clase B como privada y su implementación oculta a las otras clases incluida la clase A, excepto al método RestaA de dicha clase porque es amigo.

Comment: En tu solución `B` no forma parte de `A` como sí sucedía en la pregunta original. No se si es un requerimiento.

Comment: Asi es, A contiene un objeto de la clase B y un metodo de A requiere acceso a un metodo privado de ese objeto.